# How to build libhexagon_nn_skel.so for tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

TFLite hexagon delegate is based on hexagon nnlib, I can get nnlib source code from https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/hexagon_nn/nnlib, and I can build ibhexagon_nn_skel.so according to "README.HOW_TO_BUILD" in nnlib, but my build libhexagon_nn_skel.so can not be used for tflite, report some error.
Does tflite modify the nnlib code ? how to build libhexagon_nn_skel.so using the nnlib source code ?

Answer (score 1):

libhexagon_nn_skel.so tflite provides are usually more recent than the code on 
https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/hexagon_nn/nnlib
Also, the libraries are signed by qualcomm and that allows it to run on multiple platforms.
Building your own version requires you to create a test signature and these testsigs and .so won't work on production devices